# How to recognize german umlauts in word boundary?

Tags: regex, cpu-word, diacritics

My problem can be seen in this example: https://regex101.com/r/dToBvm/1/

I am trying to catch all words by using this regex `\b([äöüÄÖÜß\w]+)\b`

The funny thing is that "säs" will get matched, but not "äss", or "sää".
If a word starts with an umlaut or ends with it then it won't match.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks @Emma. I didn't know this one. I added some conditions cause I usually wanted to match any word with three chars. I now finally did this: https://regex101.com/r/FAk8qd/2

Could there be a better regex for this than the one I've build?

Answer (score 1):

Because word boundary is matched between `ä` and `s` in `äss` and between `s` and `ä` in `sää` (that's how `\b` is defined).

You need to use negative lookarounds to achieve what you want:

`(?<![äöüÄÖÜß\w])([äöüÄÖÜß\w]+)(?![äöüÄÖÜß\w])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dToBvm/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think your expression is good, maybe we would slightly modify that to:

```
(?<=^|\s)([\p{L}\p{N}]{3})(?=[\s.,]+|$)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/A5wi84/1), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/A5wi84/11debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

More general solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945933/1029371

```js
console.log('asdöö.ÄÄ-asdas'.split(/(?<!\p{Letter})(\p{Letter}+)(?!\p{Letter})/u))
```